# Загрузка нескольких файлов на сервер Django

Tags: python, html, django, файлы

Всем доброго времени суток.
Мне нужно загрузить несколько файлов на сервер. Вот мой код, работающий с одним файлом:

upload.html

```
        <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <br><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="{{ dir }}">
            <label id="inputFile">Выбрать файл<input type="file" name="file" id="input"                                                 onchange="inputChanged()"></label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label id="nameOfFile">Файл не выбран</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" id="btnsubmit">
        </form>
```

views.py

```
class UploadFile(View):
    def post():
        # Проверки и вычисление директории, в которую должен быть загружен файл
        file = request.FILES['file']
        fs.save(name=filename, content=file)
        return redirect(...)
```

Этот код прекрасно работает, но только с одним файлом, а мне нужно чтобы можно было загружать несколько файлов одновременно.
Не хочу пользоваться формами и моделями, так как проверки необходимы. Их намного проще сделать в моём коде, а не привязывать к событию создания модели. Да и сам смысл проекта не подразумевает хранение файлов в виде моделей.

Так как я могу обработать сразу несколько файлов?

Comment: В документации даже пример есть.

Comment: Могли бы вы пожалуйста дать ссылку или хотя бы название раздела? А то читать всю документацию нет вермени.